# mooml template returning null when attempting to render

Tags: javascript, templates, mootools

I'm trying to render a mooml template I created on the fly and am getting null when I call render.

Here is my code:

```
var myTpl = Mooml.Template('tpl', function() {
  div({class: 'new-container'},
    div({class: 'new-title'},
      div({class: 'new-text'},
        'Put your title here:'
      ),
      div({class: 'new-input'},
        input({type: 'text', name: 'title', class: 'required', title: 'Title'})
      )
    ),
    div({class: 'new-content'},
      form({method: 'post', action: '#'},
        textarea({name: 'content', style: 'width: 100%'})
      )
    )
  );
});

// el is null after executing render
var el = myTpl.render();
```

I looked at some of the variables in firebug and the myTpl var isn't null and neither is the render method.  I don't know much about what mooml is doing under the hood, but I would think what I have should work given the following example which is found [here](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mooml):

```
var template = new Mooml.Template('mytemplate', function() {
    div('Template on the fly');
});

template.render(); // returns <div>Template on the fly</div>
```

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heh, i had a horrid time looking at this, mostly because your nested tags are written so messy and looking for a mismatch/syntax error it made me overlook the fact that you fail to insitgate the class properly.

```
var foo = new Mooml.Template('tpl', function() {
    div({"class": 'new-container'},
        div({"class": 'new-title'},
            div({"class": 'new-text'}, 'Put your title here:'),
            div({"class": 'new-input'},
                input({
                      type: 'text',
                      name: 'title',
                      "class": 'required',
                      title: 'Title'
                })
            )
        ),
        div({"class": 'new-content'},
            form({method: 'post', action: '#'},
                textarea({
                    name: 'content',
                    style: 'width: 100%'
                })
            ) // form
        ) // new-content
    ); // end div function
}).render();

foo.inject(document.body);
```

this works. http://jsfiddle.net/YKTyL/2/

notice `new Mooml.Template` as opposed to passing a reference to the class itself. it's staring us right there from the example which is correct...

also, i changed instances where you say class: something as class is a reserved keyword in IE and needs to be quoted in " "

Comment: *face-palm*  I've done that before.  Thanks for taking the time.  As soon as I get back to my machine I'll give it a try.

Comment: also, thanks for pointing out that class is a reserved word in IE.  That little nugget probably saved me a lot of frustration down the road.

Comment: use jslint or even better, jshint to run through code when possible. i use webstorm/phpstorm IDE for js, which jslints in real time and it also catches improper use of reserved keywords, undefineds and all sorts. makes js dev fun again, it even understands mootools as long as it's included as a part of your project so it can parse the .js files :)